# Er raucht Selbstgedrehte

Tags: translation

I haven't understood this sentence.

**Er raucht Selbstgedrehte.**

I know that the selbstgedrehte means roll up but the sentence make no sense to me 
Because it's translation is *He smokes roll up.*

Comment: In English: He smokes [roll-ups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-your-own_cigarette). (Or: He rolls his own.)

Answer (score 9):

Es handelt sich um eine **Substantivierung**, d.h. die selbstgedrehte Zigarette ist hier zur Selbstgedrehten verkürzt worden.

- Wir braten heute Geschnetzeltes.
- Wir essen Eingekochtes.
- Sie trägt Selbstgestricktes.
- Er präsentierte das Erlernte.

Solche Substantivierungen kann man nicht nach Belieben vornehmen. Sie bürgen sich nur gelegentlich ein.

- Er erhängte sich am Selbstgedrehten.

Hier wüsste niemand so recht, ob ein Strick gemeint ist.

CarstenS fragt nach weiteren Pluralformen:

- In Rio marschierten wieder die *Gedopten* auf.
- *Tätowierte* sind heute nicht notwendig Seeleute oder Haftentlassene.

Answer (score 3):

It's an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)):

*selbstgedrehte **Zigaretten*** - cigarettes that weren't bought pre-made, but made by the smoker themself using tobacco and a cigarette paper (and perhaps a filter).

Comment: Thanks sir, that really smokescreen. I understand it know

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass das eine Ellipse ist, vielmehr halte ich es für eine Substantivierung, wie Geschnetzeltes, Eingekochtes oder Selbstgestricktes. Die Beispiele bei Wikipedia (de) listen auch kein analoges Beispiel.